# GeoJSON layer does not get recreated when rendered using EmberJS's 'link-to' helper

Tags: javascript, ember.js, leaflet

I am trying to render a LeafletJS map where the colours of the states in the map are dependent on a global parameter that is set in the appropriate Ember route. The setting of the parameter is not the issue but rather the (re)creation of the geoJson layer. When hitting the URL for the first time or when reloading the page the correct map is created, however when the page is rendered using Ember's 'link-to' helper, the map still holds the state colours of the previous page.

```
drawAll: function() {
var that = this;
Ember.$.ajax('/data/sa_provinces.json').then( function(data){
  Frontend.globalPaths = data;
  that.get('store').findAll('province').then(function(provinces) {
    provinces.forEach(function(province) {
      var provinceGeoJSON = window.L.geoJson( province.get('dataFromJSON'),
                                              { style: province.get('geoJSONStyle'),
                                                province: province,
                                                onEachFeature: province.get('onEachFeature') });
      province.set('geo_json', provinceGeoJSON);
      provinceGeoJSON.addTo(Frontend.map);
      window.province = province;
    });
  });
});
  }.property('drawAll')
```

This *drawAll* function is located within a Ember controller and is called from an Ember template. The functions *dataFromJSON*, *geoJSONStyle* and *onEachFeature* are all called the first time a page is called or when the page is refreshed but not when the page is rendered using the Ember's 'link-to' helper. Neither are they called when the URL is entered manually.

If anyone has any ideas or experience with LeafletJS and/or Ember I would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance, Greg.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue I notice is that drawAll is a computed property, not a function - you seem to be confusing computed properties and functions.

http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/

Ember computed properties are more like normal attributes that observe other variables, and recompute when those variables change. The property() method after the function declaration changes it into a computed property and specifies which variables the property depends on. On the last line you're specifying that drawAll observes itself, which doesn't make much sense.

You can't call functions from handlebars templates - you can only access properties. So you can access a property, with the side effect of causing that property's function to be called.

If you want just a function that is called as soon as the template loads, you can implement the didInsertElement function on that templates corresponding view, and the contents of the didInsertElement function will run when the template loads.

If you want a property that recomputes based on some conditions changing, you should change the last line to specify which conditions it is observing.

I can't be sure without more info about the template and controller you're using, but for your current use case it looks like you just want a function that runs whenever the template is inserted, so changing the drawAll to an actual function (by removing the .property('drawAll)) and calling it from didInsertElement of the corresponding view will rerun it every time the controller is inserted. Like:

```
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.drawAll()
  }
```

(You need to have created a view that corresponds to the controller in this context)